# Show List value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a `List` and a `DataGridView`. I added elements to the `List`, but when I tried to show that `List` value in the `DataGridView`, it's not shown.

```
public partial class Queries : Form {
    List<EmployeeDetails> lst = new List<EmployeeDetails> { };

    public Queries() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
        emp.id = Convert.ToInt32(numId.Value);
        emp.name = tbName.Text;
        emp.malecheck = rbMale.Checked;
        emp.femealecheck = rbFemale.Checked;
        lst.Add(emp);
    }

    private void btnDataGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        LinqdataGridView.DataSource = lst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your problem in better English? It's not clear from the code also what you are trying to achieve? You have posted the same code twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BindingSource`, try this;

```
private void btnDataGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var source = new BindingSource();
    source.Datasource = lst;
    LinqdataGridView.DataSource = source;
}
```

Hope helps,